# Converting a numpy ndarray to 1 dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text features which I convert to numeric using tfidf Vectorizer. The `complaint` text column is converted as below

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=5,ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english')
complain_features = tfidf.fit_transform(df.complaint.values.astype('str')).toarray()
```

`complain_features` is a 2D numpy array. I convert it to dataframe using below

```
complain_df = pd.DataFrame(complain_features, index=range(complain_features.shape[0]),
                          columns=range(complain_features.shape[1]))
```

As you can see in the attached image below. `complain_df` is a 39 column df but I need it to be 1 column. How do I do that? Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: `TfidfVectorizer` isnt a part of pandas as far as I know, if you do tag pandas , please be specific and create a sample dataframe (pandas specific) and expected output: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
complain_df['Column1'] =complain_df[complain_df.columns[1:]].apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1
)
complain_df
```